# How to setup default IGNITE_HOME environment variable in intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ignite

I want to setup default  **IGNITE_HOME = /home/arjun/Desktop/apache-ignite-2.7.0-bin** environmental variable to my whole project test classes instead of setting every time for new classes.

How can i setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got to `Run -> Edit Configurations -> Defaults`, choose a default you use during testing (e.g. `Application` for regular Java programs or `JUnit` for JUnit tests) and change the environment variables there. From now on the new configurations you add (e.g. when start a new test) will have these settings.

Note that the old configurations (e.g. the programs you've already run) won't be affected. You need to delete the existing configurations so that they're recreated with new defaults. Choose each configuration that is not in `Defaults` and hit `del` or the red minus sign.

Comment: I add that in that path. But still it's not recognizing that path  " IGNITE_HOME = /home/arjun/Desktop/apache-ignite-2.7.0-bin".

Comment: You should remove white space before and after the equals sign. Do you have screenshot?

Comment: @Mallikharjuna delete all configurations under `Application`, then try starting a program again.

Comment: @StanislavLukyanov i didn't get you. Can you please say precisely.

Comment: @Mallikharjuna Click on `DeleteTablesTest` in the `Run/Debug Configuration` window. Hit `Delete`. Run `DeleteTablesTest` again - the configuration will be recreated with the new environment variables.

Comment: @StanislavLukyanov. Prefect. It's works. Thanks, thanks every one

Answer (score 0):

Run - Edit Configurations - 选中 Application 下需要配置的项 - 右侧 Configuration 选项 - 配置 Environment variables - 添加环境变量即可。

Run - Edit Configurations - xxx - Right:Configuration - Environment variables

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I92iO.png)

Comment: @Ranger_Zhou please use English in your answer when you're at SO.

Comment: yea, So I write like this:
Run - Edit Configurations - xxx - Right:Configuration - Environment variables